how to make loop animation on bazier curve with multiple object and it disappear at the end of path?

i try  to make arrow follow along path like this and the arrow will disappear at the end of the path right now the arrow keep on going infinity i try this only on 1 arrow. planning to make something like in the picture, how to achieve something like in the picture?

Well, animate the arrows to disappear ? I don't understand what is your issue.

you can make its material transparent at the end?
